# Appending to a Javascript String using ?: in the expression behaves unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

```
var aString = "test ";

aString = aString + true?"Appended":"No Append";  // 'Appended'
```

where as

```
aString = aString + (true?"Appended":"No Append");// 'test Appended'
```

What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case adds `true` to `aString` and then checks with the ternary.

It is basically this operation with parenthesis

```
(aString + true) ? "Appended" : "No Append"
```

The overall answer is the operator precedence of `+` over `?`.

```js
var aString = "test ";

console.log(aString + true ? "Appended" : "No Append"); // 'Appended'
console.log((aString + true) ? "Appended" : "No Append"); // 'Appended'
console.log(aString + (true ? "Appended" : "No Append")); // 'test Appended'
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that javascript Operator precedence([look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence))

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case aString + true is evaluated before the rest of the expression.

So you get

```
if(aString + true) {
    aString = "Appended";
}
```

which you fixed with brackets, turning it into

```
if(true) {
    aString = aString + "Appended";
}
```